# Serializefield for UnityAction in inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script with :

```
[SerializeField]
private List<UnityAction> m_method = new List<UnityAction>();
private List<Button> m_button = new List<Button>();

void Start()
{
    //init m_button 
}


// this function is called when the player click on an object in game
void onClick()
{
    for(int i=0; i<m_button.Count; i++)
        m_button[i].AddListener(m_method[i]);
}
```

I want to define the unityAction from inspector, but nothing appears in inspector...
I thought it would be something like the button component :
[image]

**Is there a way of binding action to buttons with serialize field in inspector ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is not `UnityAction`, is`UnityEvent`, this last one can be serialized on to the inspector.

Difference is well explained in [UnityForums](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1596466/unityaction-vs-unityevent.html#:%7E:text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%20it%27s,onClick%20event%20of%20a%20Button%20.).

> `UnityAction` is like:
>
> ```
>  public delegate void UnityAction();
> ```
>
> And `UnityEvent` is just another way to handle events **with the
> (great) possibility to be serialized so as to be used in the Editor**
> (Inspector) in contrary to plain C# events. A simple example is the
> onClick event of a Button.

If you want to pass UnityEvent to the AddListener method, you can use lambda expresions like this:

```
btn.onClick.AddListener(() => unityEvent?.Invoke());
```

Notice the "`?`" to avoi calling null (empty) actions!

Comment: Yes I tried UnityEvent, but the function AddListener doesn't accept unityEvent... Then if I have unityEvent how can I bind the unityEvent to the buttons ?

Comment: @lufydad I've updated the answer, One way: btn.onClick.AddListener(() => unityEvent?.Invoke());